# Changing font colour with Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, fonts

Apologies for this one but I'm way out of my depth!

I've put together the following Javascript which does a great job of displaying a ticking timer (from 10:00 to 0:00) in a HTML class of **timer**.

```js
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("timer")
var timings = 600;
var i = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(Timeout, 1000);

function Timeout() {
  if ((timings - i) % 60 >= 10) {
    time[0].innerHTML = parseInt(`${(timings-i)/60}`) + ":" + `${(timings-i)%60}`;
  } else {
    time[0].innerHTML = parseInt(`${(timings-i)/60}`) + ":0" + `${(timings-i)%60}`;
  }
  i++;
  if ((timings - i) % 60 < 0) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timer"></div>
```

What I want the code to do is change the font colour to red when the timer reaches 0:59. I've tried various solutions but I don't know what the correct code would be **or** where to put it as every option I've tried has simply broken the script.

Would anyone out there be able to shed some light and save the small handful of hair I have left?!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: either add style attribute to the element e.g. `time[0].style.color='red'` or add a class - e.g. `time[0].classList.add('red')` where your css includes `.red { color:red }`

Comment: Which solutions have you tried and what specifically went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the good of the hair, I added a condition (timings - i) === 59 inside the Timeout function. This condition checks if the remaining time is equal to 59 seconds, which corresponds to 0:59 on the timer. When this condition is true, it sets the font color of the timer element to red using time[0].style.color = "red";.

```js
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("timer");
var timings = 100;
var i = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(Timeout, 1000);

function Timeout() {
  if ((timings - i) % 60 >= 10) {
    time[0].innerHTML = parseInt(`${(timings - i) / 60}`) + ":" + `${(timings - i) % 60}`;
  } else {
    time[0].innerHTML = parseInt(`${(timings - i) / 60}`) + ":0" + `${(timings - i) % 60}`;
  }

  if ((timings - i) === 59) {
    time[0].style.color = "red";
  }

  i++;
  if ((timings - i) % 60 < 0) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}
```

```html
 
      <div class="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Guess I need to buy myself a Javascript primer and read up on this stuff because, once you provided the solution, it was so obvious! You're a legend. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, we all had that moment when you stare at the code long enough even simple stuff can't get to your mind anymore, it's called burnout ;)